# How to force Ubuntu use AC power instead of laptop battery

Tags: battery

I have replaced my laptop battery twice and now I want to do something to help my laptop!

Is there anyway to force Ubuntu use ac power instead of laptop battery?

I don't want to use battery sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When plugged in to the AC power, the AC power is used rather than the laptop.

If you look into the bios of your computer, you may be able to set that charging should not go above a certain percentage, or should only start when below a certain threshold. Not having your battery charged 100% all the time will increase the life time of the battery.

If the battery is removable, you can consider removing it, and only inserting it when on the road. A more limited use also will increase the life time. Drawback, however, is that the computer is at risk if there is a power outage.